# Images are not displayed on django

Tags: python, django, image

I have a problem with path image in django, When I put in  the path from the model (item.img) and start the server, I don't see the image because the image path doesn't contain /media/.but if I add /media/ before {{item.url}} everything is going right

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

My code:
-setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.CustomUser'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

-urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('items.urls')),
    ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=sett
```

-html

```
  <div class="main__column">
                <div class="main__item item">
                    <div class="item__img">
                        {% for img in p.image_set.all %}
                        {{img.main_image}}
                        <img src="{{img.main_image}}" alt="">
                        {%endfor%}
                    </div>
                    <div class="item__body">
                        <div class="item__name">{{p.name}}</div>
                        <div class="item__descriptions">{{p.descriptions}}</div>
                        <div class="item__price">{{p.price}}</div>
                        <div class="item__in_stock">{{p.in_stock}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have looked for a solution to the problem in other forums. I am waiting for someone's help

Answer (score 1):

Add **`{{img.main_image.url}}`** in src argument of img tag

```
<img src="{{img.main_image.url}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I needed to call the .url after the image field
`{{item.image.url}}`.